# Neural networks - unable to understand the behaviour of the output layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'd like to know why this works (look for the comment "*# This is the output layer and this is what I am talking about*"):

```
model = Sequential() # Not talking about this
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1])) # Not talking about this
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) # Not talking about this
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # Not talking about this
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) # Not talking about this
model.add(Dense(y_train.nunique()+1, activation='softmax')) # This is the output layer and this is what I am talking about
          
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.01), metrics=['accuracy']) # Not talking about this
model.summary() # Not talking about this
```

and not this (look for the comment "*# This is the output layer and this is what I am talking about*")::

```
model = Sequential() # Same as above
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim = X_train.shape[1])) # Same as above
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) # Same as above
model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # Same as above
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu')) # Same as above
model.add(Dense(y_train.nunique(), activation='softmax')) # This is the output layer and this is what I am talking about
          
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.01), metrics=['accuracy']) # Same as above
model.summary() # Same as above
```

So what's going on here is that I have this very basic NN that I am using to predict a multiclass dataset. There are 10 classes in the target, starting from 0 and going all the way to 10 (with the exception of 9; 9 isn't there). At where I've commented "*# This is the output layer and this is what I am talking about*", when I give the unit of output neurons as the number of unique values of target (`y_train.nunique()`), it throws an error like this:

```
Detected at node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits defined at (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
...

  File "c:\<redacted>\Projects\<redacted>\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5775, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 5 0 3 3 1 8 10 4 3 1 0 0 1 3 5 6 10 6 10 8 4 6 6 6 1 2 7 10 8 0 4 8
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_737445]
```

On the other hand, when I give the number of units as anything more than that, like in the above example it is `y_train.nunique()+1`, it goes through all 200 epochs. I don't understand what's going on.

Also,

1. Is the output layer correct (for the number of classes in question)?
2. Is my understanding of the output layer correct (which is - for this specific problem - the number of neurons in the output must be equal to the number of unique values of the target (which are also the classes the data falls into))?

Comment: The problem is that 9 is not there, class indices must go from 0 to num_classes - 1

Comment: It is apparently `number of classes + 1`, and it is working, and also apparently it's the right way to do this, as confirmed by Mulikan in the answer below, but thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Actually no, num_classes works fine, only if your class indices do not have gaps, as I said, the class indices need to go from 0 to num_classes - 1, your specific problem is because there is a gap, one of the classes is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I understand your question.
**The output layer should be equal to the number of  target classes.** For Example in your case take output neuron as `y_train.nunique() is 10` then the final layer output and label should be in **the range of 0 - 9.** The Label value 10 will be not included in that specific range. **So It throw error Received a label value of 10 which is outside the valid range becasuse the label 10 will not include in the final softmax neuron number of 10**

[image]

**The Above image will represent the softmax layer with the classes of 3. [0.9% is class 0, 0.1% is class 1, 0.0% is class 2]** If Number of class 10 Only 10 class probability in softmax will be created. **In your case the number of classes will be 11.**

If `y_train.nunique() + 1 is 10` then the final layer output and label should be **in the range of 0 - 10 here for the 10th class the probability softmax will be created.** So the code works fine.

**Sum of all classes probability will be result in 1. The missing 9 is also will be consider as one class**

Comment: Wow, thanks for that detailed explanation. Kinda nice to know what I thought was a workaround wasn't a workaround, but the solution itself!

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Actually this tells you why the workaround works, the workaround is not actually the solution itself. Fix your class indices to not have gaps.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Yes, but remember Practically it fine. but technically you need to fix the label of the missing class It will be an issue to a model while learning from the 
 data feature.

Comment: Ahh, OK I see what you're saying. So if I make the 10s as 9s, I don't need to `+1`.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson Yes, you can make 10s as 9s for the model training. In the Inference also you will get 9s instead of 10s. I hope you clear